# Why does my string violate constraints?

Tags: java, regex, bean-validation

This is my @Pattern.List:

```
@NotNull
@Pattern.List({
        @Pattern(regexp="[A-Z][a-z]+\\s[A-Z][a-z]+", message="Name contains invalid characters."),
        @Pattern(regexp="[A-Z][a-z]+", message="Name contains invalid characters.")
        })
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

The string is North Dakota.

I admit I'm not the best at regex and I'm new to this, but shouldn't that work?

It works if I remove the @Pattern annotation.

This is the error:

`Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.`

Comment: don't you need brackets around `[A-Z][a-z]` to indicate the `+` sign applies to both of them?

Comment: I think it only applies to [a-z] I only want one capital letter at the beginning.

Comment: Oh like that, nevermind then.

Comment: Your two regex's can by simplified into one by making the second string optional using `?` => `[A-Z][a-z]+(\\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?`

Comment: still getting  `Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.`

Comment: Your pattern is matching the string `North Dakota`. Are you sure that this string is submittted? Is there any empty space at the end or special additional character?

Comment: I know it is because when I remove the annotation it submits just fine.

Comment: Please try to separate the responsibilities/concerns of each of the Java EE APIs. You tagged JSF while nothing of all those validation annotations is coming from `javax.faces` package. It's "Bean Validation" (also known as JSR303). This is thus not JSF related. Also, you called it in the title a "JSF entity", while the `@Entity` annotation isn't from `javax.faces` package at all. It's from JPA, but even then without it being an entity you'd still have faced the same problem, thus also not JPA related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to expect that when you provide a `@Pattern.List`, that the value should then match *at least one* pattern of the list. But this is not true. The value must match *any one* pattern of the list. In case of "North Dakota", only the first pattern matches, but the second not. Hence you keep seeing this constraint violation error.

The `@Pattern.List` should only be used for patterns which cannot be represented by a single pattern, or each needs a dfferent message (such as complex password matching on various types of characters).

In this particular case, you just need to simplify the regular expression into **one** pattern wherein you specify the second word as optional by placing it in `(...)?`.

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="[A-Z][a-z]+(\\s[A-Z][a-z]+)?", message="Name contains invalid characters.")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```